# Absolute irreducibility of residual representation

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $\rho: G_\mathbb{Q} \to \operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb{F}_p)$ be an odd irreducible representation ($p \neq 2$). I am trying to understand the following proof by Serre: Let $c$ be a complex conjugation. Now $\rho(c)$ has eigenvalues $1$ and $-1$. Suppose that $\rho$ decomposes over $\bar{\mathbb{F}}_p$ into a direct sum of two one-dimensional representations. This decomposition then would have to be given by the eigenvalues $1$ and $-1$ so it would be over $\mathbb{F}_p$ contradicting irreducibility. What is going on here? Why considering only one automorphism (complex conjugation) is enough?

Comment: You ask "Why considering only one automorphism (complex conjugation) is enough?"  In fact, $c$ could be considered a whole conjugacy class of automorphisms.  It turns out that the nontrivial elements of finite order in $G_\mathbf Q$ are the conjugates of $c$ and nothing more.  So what Serre is looking at is essentially $\rho$ on nontrivial torsion in $G_\mathbf Q$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says that if $p\ne 2$ and $\rho(c)\ne \pm 1$ (so $\rho(c)$ is diagonalizable and has the two $1,-1$ eigenvalues)

and if there is $v\in \overline{\Bbb{F}}_p^2-(0,0)$ such that  $\forall \sigma, \rho(\sigma) v= \chi(\sigma) v$  with $\chi(\sigma) \in \overline{\Bbb{F}}_p^*$

then $v\in \ker(\rho(c)\pm 1)$ which gives that $v=\alpha w$ with $\alpha \in \overline{\Bbb{F}}_p^*, w\in \Bbb{F}_p^2 - (0,0)$,

and so $\Bbb{F}_p w$ is a subrepresentation of $\Bbb{F}_p^2$.